# I have a plane (one face). I have an Image texture. How do I make a bone that moves the image texture along the plane?

Tags: mesh, uv

I'm trying to rig a very simple eye.

The white of the eye is a plane (the plane is in Circle shape).
The image texture is my pupil.

How do I get the Pupil texture to move correctly along the Plane with a bone controlling the pupil movement? The method I've found online involves Cameras and that sounds insanely complicated for what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Comment: You might be able to do that with UV project, but I need at leas a screenshot or 2 to go into detail.

Comment: Hello! I edited the post with a screenshot. I guess it's not technically a Plane, but a Mesh Circle that is filled in. Let me know if more information is wanted. Basically I'd like the pupil image to be able to move along the Circle's surface, so that even if in the future I deform the Circle to bend a bit forward, the Pupil would still track over its geometry correctly. The pupil needs to be controlled with a Bone because it's for a Unity project.